# Kotlin set Array as key for a HashMap

Tags: python, arrays, kotlin

I'm doing a bit of Leetcode, and I'm facing this issue: [Group Anagrams](https://leetcode.com/problems/group-anagrams/), I have a Python background and I can do the following:

```
res = defaultdic(list)

count = [0] * 26

res[tuple(count)].append(s)
```

as we can see we can set the tupled array as the key for the dictionary, I want to do the same thing in Kotlin, however, when creating this in Kotlin, I get a different object every time when adding this logic in a for loop.

```
fun groupAnagrams(strs: Array<String>): List<List<String>> {
    val hashMap = hashMapOf<IntArray, ArrayList<String>>()

    for (word in strs) {
        val array = IntArray(26) { 0 }

        for (char in word) {
            val charInt = char - 'a'

            array[charInt] += 1
        }

        if (hashMap.containsKey(array)) {
            hashMap[array]!!.add(word)
        } else {
            hashMap[array] = ArrayList<String>().apply { add(word) }
        }
    }

    return hashMap.values.toList()
}
```

Is this something can be done in Kotlin?

Comment: Alternatively to the provided solution one could also use the contentHashCode of an array like this: `hashMap[array.contentHashCode()]` This eliminated the need to use a List.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Equality for `IntArray` is checked based on its reference. You can use a `List` here in place of `IntArray`. Two `List`s are equal if they contain the same elements.

Modified code will be like this:

```kotlin
fun groupAnagrams(strs: Array<String>): List<List<String>> {
    val hashMap = hashMapOf<List<Int>, ArrayList<String>>()

    for (word in strs) {
        val array = List(26) { 0 }.toMutableList()

        for (char in word) {
            val charInt = char - 'a'
            array[charInt] += 1
        }

        if (hashMap.containsKey(array)) {
            hashMap[array]!!.add(word)
        } else {
            hashMap[array] = ArrayList<String>().apply { add(word) }
        }
    }

    return hashMap.values.toList()
}
```

Comment: May also be worth renaming `array` since it's no longer an array :-) And worth pointing out that if you use mutable objects as map keys, you _must_ ensure that they can't change thereafter; if they do, then the map can behave inconsistently, being unable to find keys or even throwing exceptions.

Comment: Are you referring to this code in your second point? I didn't get that. Where are mutable keys here?

Comment: My second was a general point that people should be aware of, not a problem with anything in your answer. (Feel free to add it to your answer if you want.)

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding the problem you run into (equality of arrays) by using `String` keys:

```kotlin
fun groupAnagramsWithHashing(strs: Array<String>): List<List<String>> {
    val map = hashMapOf<String, MutableList<String>>()

    MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1").also { sha ->
        for (word in strs) {
            word.toByteArray().sorted().forEach { sha.update(it) }

            val key = sha.digest().joinToString()
            map.computeIfAbsent(key) { mutableListOf() }.add(word)
        }
    }
    return map.values.toList()
}

fun main() {
    val input = arrayOf("eat", "tea", "tan", "ate", "nat", "bat")
    groupAnagramsWithHashing(input).also { println(it) }
    // [[eat, tea, ate], [bat], [tan, nat]]
}
```